# How do I determine whether curreltly connected wifi is secure or not in iPhone or iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, wifi

Is there any way to determine currently connected wifi is secure or not in the iOS SDK?

I also read some article that says Apple does not provide any SDK related to the wifi connection.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? there are few application in the market which has the ability to identify this. I am wondering how those applications are working without any availability of public APIS?

Answer (score 2):

Apple does does indeed not provide API access to the WiFi settings or connection settings on that level

If you want to make sure that the connection is secure use SSL.